# Divide selenium python files in smaller chunks

Tags: python, selenium

I have a few python files for testing my page and now these files have become many and they all share

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

And this

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Is it possible to just import these in my other runs? If so, how?

I have tried having this in an own file called start.py and then using

```
from start import setUp
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Please explain how putting `setUp` in it's own module and importing it with `from start import setUp` did not work. What didn't work? Please provide error information. You were on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, create a base test class and have all your test classes inherit it. Having said, i dont know if the webdriver will play along well (untested)

```
import unittest

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('--- Setup ---')

    def tearDown(self):
        print('--- Tear Down ---')


class Test1(BaseTest):

    def test_equal(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)


class Test2(BaseTest):

    def test_equal(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Output:**

```
--- Setup ---
.--- Tear Down ---
--- Setup ---
--- Tear Down ---
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s
```